# For Jira Server how to access or prepare FieldMetaBean Object for OrderableField and CustomField Objects

Tags: field, metadata, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to get the FieldMetaBean Object for Orderable and CustomField. But Could only get the JsonType Objects for the fields. Has anyone tried to access FieldMetaBean Object of this fields or tried to prepare it.

```
  IssueCreationHelperBean issueCreationHelperBean = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueCreationHelperBean.class);
                List<OrderableField> orderableFields = issueCreationHelperBean.getFieldsForCreate(ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser(), issuePattern);
                JsonArray fields = new JsonArray();
                for(OrderableField orderableField : orderableFields) {
                    JsonObject field = new JsonObject();
                    field.addProperty("name", orderableField.getName());
                    field.addProperty("key", orderableField.getNameKey());

                    // Get FieldMetaBean Object

                    fields.add(field);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have found the Solution please find below

```
        List<Project> extProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    if (projectIds != null && !projectIds.isEmpty()) {
        Long projectId = Long.parseLong(projectIds);
        Project project = ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager().getProjectObj(projectId);
        if (project != null) {
            extProjects.add(project);
        }
    } else {
        extProjects.addAll(ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager().getProjects());
    }
    JsonArray projJsonArray = new JsonArray();

    if (extProjects != null && !extProjects.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < extProjects.size(); i++) {
            Project project = extProjects.get(i);
            List<IssueType> issueTypes = new ArrayList<IssueType>();
            issueTypes.addAll(project.getIssueTypes());
            JsonObject projectJson = new JsonObject();
            projectJson.addProperty("id", project.getId());
            projectJson.addProperty("key", project.getKey());
            projectJson.addProperty("name", project.getName());

            JsonArray issueTypesJsonArray = new JsonArray();
            for (IssueType issueType : issueTypes) {
                JsonObject issueTypeJson = new JsonObject();
                issueTypeJson.addProperty("id", issueType.getId());
                issueTypeJson.addProperty("description", issueType.getDescription());
                issueTypeJson.addProperty("name", issueType.getName());
                issueTypeJson.addProperty("subtask", issueType.isSubTask());
                issueTypeJson.addProperty("expand", "fields");
                MutableIssue issuePattern = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueFactory.class).getIssue();
                issuePattern.setProjectId(project.getId());
                issuePattern.setIssueTypeId(issueType.getId());
                IssueCreationHelperBean issueCreationHelperBean = ComponentAccessor
                        .getComponentOfType(IssueCreationHelperBean.class);
                FieldScreenRenderer fieldScreenRenderer = issueCreationHelperBean
                        .createFieldScreenRenderer(issuePattern);
                Map<String, FieldMetaBean> fieldsMap = getFieldMetadataBeans(issuePattern, issueType, project,
                        fieldScreenRenderer);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                issueTypeJson.add("fields", gson.toJsonTree(fieldsMap));
                issueTypesJsonArray.add(issueTypeJson);
            }
            projectJson.add("issuetypes", issueTypesJsonArray);
            projJsonArray.add(projectJson);
        }
    }

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.add("projects", projJsonArray);
    jsonObject.addProperty("expand", "projects");
    jsonObject.addProperty("total", Integer.valueOf(projJsonArray.size()));
    return jsonObject;
```